# Node.js passing variable in MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to pass a variable to a MongoDB query inside my Node.js app yet it is always returning empty records. The only way to return results is by hardcoding the variable value in the query as shown below. Can someone please tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here and how to fix it? Thanks for your time and support

Query (Hardcoded):

```
db.items.find({"item_id": "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312", itemtype: '1'});
```

Query with variable:

```
let x = '5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312';
db.items.find({"item_id": x, itemtype: '1'});
```

Comment: Where does the variable come from? Do you obtain it from user input maybe? Please verify that the variable indeed has the expected value (debug, use console.log, whatever).

Comment: Variable is being read from DB

Comment: OK, then please verify the variable contains the correct value.

Comment: There's likely a string vs. ObjectId issue here. Make sure both `x` and `item_id` are the same type.